# Unity UI making it responsive

Tags: unity, ui-design

I am attempting to create a simple `Jeopardy` game using the UI features of Unity:

However as im trying to change the size of the screen it does not seem that my UI is responsive:

Here is it in 16:9:

[image]

Here it is in 600x900[image]

My Question is. is there a way to make it responsive?

Is it even nessary to do so in unity or am i thinking way to much web based? :)

Hope someone is able to help me and guide me abit

Comment: May that helps a bit: [Responsive Unity UI for Sudoku](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130317/responsive-dynamically-changing-grid-layout-group-cell-sizes-in-unity3d-ui)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `Horizontal Layout Group` and `Vertical Layout Group`component for UI objects.

A parent UI object will have a `Vertical Layout Group`component and it's child objects will have a `Horizontal Layout Group` component. Then your objects with `Text` will be placed under these `Horizontal Layout Group` component holding objects.

[image]

On the `Text` components, tick `Best Fit` for font size and align as you need.

*I named the objects as their components for clarification.*

**Games are usually oriented either Landscape or Portrait. Using multiple orientation is bad game UX. Webpages are different than games in this case.**